# ASP.NET MVC 4 Controllers @Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to to display images from my SQL database. The final display should look like the following in the browser:

1 | Web Team | We are the best department!      View Image | Edit | Delete
(note: "View Image", "Edit", and "Delete" are all links)

When the user clicks the "View Image" link, I would like the image URL stored in the database to display the actual image.

Here is the code from my View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View Image", "viewImage", new { id = Department.Picture })
```

And here is the code from my Controller:

```
public class ViewImageController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult viewImage(int Id)
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong because you are not doing anything at all

Comment: Hmm. My thinking was that the ActionResult for viewImage would take the Id from Department.Picture and return the actual image with View(). But based off your response, the View() returns nothing at all. Suggestions on what I should use instead?

Comment: You should go fetch it from the database before returning an Action Result. You have the `Id` which is passed by the view, which is enough to find it. Do you have a configured database? Maybe some kind of Data Access Object?

Comment: You need to learn C# and asp.net mvc first. Start with some tutorials and don't just copy/paste code, try to understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public ActionResult viewImage(int Id)
{
 Byte[] byteArray = MODEL.TABLE_NAME.Where(i =>colum_name == id).Select(i => i.FILE_DATA).Single();
 return File(byteArray, "image/png"); 
}
```